# How do you set up command line args in Eclipse for the MAC? (Intent is to submit to online programming challenges)

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, command-line-arguments

I know that you must add command line arguments into the "Run Configurations" in Eclipse to get your command line arguments to be passed every time by default. This worked fine on my PC.

**The purpose of this question is to create a simple program that can be submitted to an online programming challenge site (like codeeval). The system provides a file path to the command line `args[0]` and then you manipulate the file and its data.**

On the PC I had my Class folder > Default Package > (file.txt and TestCode.java)
The project was set up with a run configuration with simply `file.txt` in the program arguments section.

On the MAC this doesn't seem to be working. I get a `fileNotFoundExcepion`. I'm new to MAC so I'm thinking this might be a problem with file extensions not being what I think they are. I saved a file as "file.txt" but if I save it as "file" MAC doesn't show the file extensions and I'm not sure if MAC supports .txt by default.

If it doesn't support `.txt`, what file type is a "text document"? I tried saving the text document as "file" leaving off any extension, and then adding `file.rtf` or `file.txt` or even `file` to the Program arguments and none of that works. It all gives me a `fileNotFoundException`.

**EDIT** 
The intent is to be able to develop solutions to the CodeEval (or similar) website and submit them. I have previously solved many problems on CodeEval and turned them in with the code below from a PC. This, however, doesn't work on MAC. The answer involving the use of the URL does not work when run from the solution checking platform (presumably because the program is not actually saved onto the system).

**EDIT 2**
My entire program:

```
public class TestCode {

    public static void main (String[] args)throws IOException{

        File filename = new File(args[0]);
        Scanner file = new Scanner(filename);  // returns the fileNotFoundException

        while( file.hasNextLine()){
            String line = file.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Under "Run Configurations" in the Arguments tab > Program Arguments I have tried putting `file`, `file.txt`, `file.rtf` all three with a "text document" in the same directory as the above program. I have tried naming that file `file`, `file.txt` and `file.rtf` And i tried every combination of these names.

Comment: Mac will treat .txt extension as normal file name. So it should not be problem with file name. It will be what path you are providing

Comment: I don't provide any path, the file is in the same directory as the TestCode.java which receives the argument.

Comment: Would you provide code snippet where you read the file

Comment: @SachinPasalkar As requested. The code should be fine. Really this whole problem should be a quick fix but I've done all I know how and it's not working.

Comment: Eclipse behaves the same on Windows and OSX for finding a file. Note that the current directory is set by Eclipse and is not by default where Test.java is, so I expect when you created the project in Windows you altered something in the project or run configuration (or at least they differ between your two OSs)

Comment: What is the actual value of args[0] under both OS's?

Comment: I think you are right. I had to use a direct file path like one of the answers below suggested, while this was not necessary on the PC. The PC has the default location as being relative to the Main .java file. MAC required an exact file path, additionally the file extension has to be left off on the MAC.

Comment: I also don't understand why this question was down-voted when nobody seems to have a clear answer to the problem (until a bounty was offered) and the question is clearly explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to use the *absolute* file name as command line parameter? This should be something like `/Users/name/path/to/your/file`. If the file is part of your project, you can also use a variable such as `${project_loc}/file` (try the button *Variables…* below the *Program Arguments* field.

Comment: On closer look you'r absolutely right. The PC didn't require an exact file path for the text file. The PC was asking for a relative file path (not sure why) and MAC needed an exact path. I used the `${project_loc}/filepath/file` (but note that .txt is not a MAC extension and this was left off). If you'll edit the answer to reflect the lack of a need for the file extension then I'll award the bounty. Thanks

Comment: Sure, if you prefer it without the file extension, here you go. Anyway, although file extensions are not essential as they are on Windows, naming a text file `file.txt` is perfectly valid and common on a Unix filesystem as well.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code with this

```
URL resource = TestCode.class.getResource(args[0]); 
Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(resource.getFile()).getAbsoluteFile());
```

Comment: This works. Can you explain the difference between this and what I had used? The intent is to be able to solve programming challenge on sites like CodeEval.com. Will this work on both my personal MAC and then translate fine to their system? Their system worked previously with code submitted from my PC (which looked identical to what I have above).

Comment: I just checked this with some of the online challenge systems and it doesn't work. I could easily change these lines back to the version I used which works on PC, but is there no format that works for both PC and MAC?

Comment: @leigero: This should work on every system as 'TestCode.class.getResource()' searches for resources in jar/classpath file